# format condition if else if and use the method inside only one time

Tags: php, arrays, code-formatting

I am developing an application, and in part of the code, I think that looks ugly to me, in fact I call an API to retrieve an array of arrays, and I use a variable to determine if I need to call on all the elements of the table or on a specific elements, so here it is

```
foreach ($this->projects['projects'] as $project) {
    if (is_array($project)) {
        if (!isset($type_project)) {  
            $this->_doProcess($project);
        } 
        elseif (isset($type_project) && ($type_project == $project['type_projet'])){
            $this->_doProcess($project);
        }
    }
}
```

is there a method to call the method doProcess One time and take on consideration the criteria of conditions ?

Comment: There is no `$type_project` defined in your loop, which makes the source of your conditions mysterious. I've fixed the indentation in your code as a first step toward better-looking code.

Comment: You can do it this  way : if(!isset($type_project) || ($type_project == $project[‘type_project’])){...call your function...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the conditions quite easily, with the understanding that whatever that's evaluated after `!isset($x) || ...` will have `isset($x)` as a given. As follows:

```
foreach ($this->projects['projects'] as $project) {
    if (is_array($project)) {
        if (!isset($type_project) || $type_project == $project['type_projet'])) {
            $this->_doProcess($project);
        }
    }
}
```

You could also tuck in the `is_array` into the same evaluation, however that'd make it a bit more obtuse to read, and as I understand your concern was simply over eliminating the extra `_doProcess()`. In any case, just so the options are spelled out:

```
foreach ($this->projects['projects'] as $project) {
    if (is_array($project) && (!isset($type_project) || $type_project == $project['type_projet']) ) {
            $this->_doProcess($project);
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, you could make it even more concise to score the single-statement holy grail:

```
foreach ($this->projects['projects'] as $project) {
    is_array($project) 
        && (!isset($type_project) || $type_project == $project['type_projet']) 
        && $this->_doProcess($project);
}
```

I find the above quite readable actually, more so when split over three lines, but the masses may disagree over whether it's good practice... I find myself doing it once in a while.